# Saving an array of values (file urls) to update_user_meta()?

Tags: user-meta, user-registration

My site allows user registration and requires users to upload documents to verify themselves. For this (and other user data) I added various user fields on the WordPress backend.

At registration I run `update_user_meta()` several times to save the values from the registration form. Like this:

`update_user_meta( $user_id, 'phone_number', $phone_number );`

This works great for normal values, but it fails me with the file uploads.

My file upload field allows the upload of several pdf documents and then returns them as an array. If I pass the result from that field similarly to the above phone number example the backend field just shows `Array`.

It would be ideal to have a separate field in the backend to display each file URL separately. To do this, I tried to build various sorts of `for` loops, but all of them so far have resulted in errors.

I'm not really sure how else to approach this...

Answer (score 0):

In parameter `$isSingle` 3th of function `get_user_meta` default value is `false` and this return value with array.Change 3th parameter to `true`.

More details https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta